# Cross compiling tpm-toool

Tags: linux, cross-compiling, tpm, trusted

I am trying to cross compile tpm-tools for powerpc. The command which
I have used for configuration is:

```
./configure --target=powerpc-linux --enable-debug
--enable-cross-compile --enable-static --disable-shared
--host=powerpc-linux
```

I have set the CC variable to the apt location, but still getting the error:

> checking for Tspi_Context_Create in -ltspi... no
>
> configure: error: tss lib not found: libtspi.so

I don't understand why tpm-tools is searching for shared libraries when I've
configured it to use static ones.
Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a work around, the cross compilation could easily be done by using https://github.com/flihp/meta-measured/tree/master/recipes-tpm/tpm-tools recipe file.